# Entity Framework, Using one connection for all application threads

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity FrameWork and i have program that save/update to different 
tables by several threads.

At first, I opened new connection to the db for every action

```
var db = new AppDBEntities()
```

AppDBEntities inherit from ObjectContext

Until i got the "Too many connections" Exception and i realized that i reached 151 
connections.

I could increase the max_connection property in the MySql DB but of course this 
is not the right solution...

So i tried to make the app use **one** connection for all the threads
and i little lost in managing this..

Any idea how to use **one** DB connection across all threads with or without using sync object(Maby Entity Framework allready have its own solution for this issue..)

Thanx.

Comment: You're opening and closing in every thread but what you really want is to open a connection before running your threads and committing/closing after they finished. All using that single connection. Right?

Comment: Exactly, One connection for all the threads, But i commit every action
immediately after the update/add action and not at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

why not put your AppDBEntities calling inside using statement and this will close the connection for you.

```
using(var db = new AppDBEntities()){
// your code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define it static in the class where you start the threads.
But you have to consider thread safety. Only 1 thread can access an object at the same time so  usually means locking it before reading/writing. I don't know in the case of a DbContext.